# dynamically Build ng-template using list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-include, ng-template

I am trying to build ng-template dynamically, In the Data structure, I have a Object that contains list of object of same type or other type of object.

```
[
                      {
                            type: "device",
                            id: 1,
                            allowedTypes: ["device","action"],
                            max: 5,
                            columns: [

                                {
                                    type: "action",
                                    id: "1"
                                },
                                {
                                      type: "device",
                                      id: 2,
                                      allowedTypes: ["device","action"],
                                      max: 5,
                                      columns: [

                                          {
                                              type: "action",
                                              id: "1"
                                          },
                                          {
                                              type: "action",
                                              id: "2"
                                          }

                                      ]
                                  }

                            ]
                        }
]
```

My ng-template code:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="and.html">
       <div class="container-element box box-red">
           <h3>And {{item.id}}</h3>

           <ul dnd-list="item.columns"
                 dnd-allowed-types="item.allowedTypes"
                   dnd-disable-if="item.columns.length >= item.max">


               <li ng-repeat="element in item.columns"
                   dnd-draggable="element"
                   dnd-effect-allowed="move"
                   dnd-moved="item.columns.splice($index, 1)"
                   dnd-selected="models.selected = element"
                   ng-class="{selected: models.selected === element}"
                   ng-include="element.type + '.html'" onload="onloadAction()">
               </li>
           </ul>

           <div class="clearfix"></div>
       </div>
   </script>
```

In the ng-template code the first level or different types of object can easily be added, however same type of object does not work properly when added in the 2nd level, it seems the its going in a recursive loop. 
This is because the nested ng-template (child) ng-template use of root item.columns from the ng-repeat="element in item.columns".

```
               <li ng-repeat="element in item.columns"
                   dnd-draggable="element"
                   ng-include="element.type + '.html'">
               </li>
```

[image: Ng-template nested]

any advise how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this issue, ng-repeat create a new child scope, however the **item**  from the parent scope is also visible to in the child scope, as this is recursive that mean child template and parent template both have the variable with the same name called **item**. However the child scope variable **item** is ignored:

```
           <li ng-repeat="element in item.columns"
               dnd-draggable="element"
               ng-include="element.type + '.html'">
           </li>
```

in the above snippet the element also has a variable called item, so in the child scope when we call item.columns the **item** variable of parent is invoked again, to ensure that the **item** variable of child is not ignored, we need to use ng-init with ng-include and set the current **element** as **item** in the child scope as shown below:

```
           <li ng-repeat="element in item.columns"
               dnd-draggable="element"
               ng-include="element.type + '.html'" ng-init="item=element">
           </li>
```

To read more on this please visit 
http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates